# Automatically submitting a form when an upload file is chosen

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, file-upload

I have a HTML page with the following input tag:

```
...
<input type="file" id="browseContactImageButton" />
...
```

Clicking the button on the page results in Open File Dialog. If I want to do the actual uploading, I need another button to click (submit), because this input file button is used just to provide the path to the file.

Is it possible to click the browse button, select the file and to start the uploading function immediately after the file has been chosen? If yes, could anyone provide the code snippet? Thanks.

Comment: removed php tag. this seems to be HTML/JavaScript only.

Comment: changed title as this has nothing to do with mysql either.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

If you want the form to submit after the user has made their selection, then simply add

```
<input type="file" onchange="this.form.submit();" ..... >
```

Comment: Correct, and in case AJAX is involved triggered by "custom" button you can have same way:  `onchange="document.getElementById('btnTrigger').click();"`

Comment: Yes, that's the handler I was missing the whole time! Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same requirement.

I figured out to use onchange event of fileupload control to fire c# method.

But I'm getting  FileUpload1.HasFile property always 'False' and file name was not set yet.

My markup:

```
<asp:FileUpload ID="FileUpload1" runat="server" ClientIDMode="AutoID" 
                        ViewStateMode="Enabled" onchange="UploadImage();"/>
```

any suggessions?