# submitting form after select file dialog has been closed

Tags: jquery, triggers, dialog, form-submit

I need to submit my upload file form after "file selection" is done.
My file input is that,

```
<input type="file" id="myfile" name="myfile" />
```

my form is

```
<form id="uploadform" action="includes/upload_img.php" ......">
```

I am using this method:

- I am creating an form and i-frame on-the-fly (via image click - img.sendimage)
- Executing select file dialog (created in form)
- Sending selected file to directory via PHP and
- Showing returned message

but, when i trigger the "Select file dialog" and select a file, form is submitting (immediately) without selected file.

My code looks like this:

```
$("img.sendimage").live('click',function(){
    $('<form id="uploadform" action="includes/upload_img.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" target="uploadframe" style="position: absolute;top: -1000px;">
    <input type="file" id="myfile" name="myfile" />
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
    <iframe id="uploadframe" name="uploadframe" src="includes/upload_img.php" width="0" height="0" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" style="visible:false;"></iframe>
    </form>').appendTo("body");
    $('#myfile').click();
    $('#uploadform').submit();
});
```

How can i trigger the form submit event after #myfile input has been closed (and file is selected as well)?

NOTE: If i use same method on seperate click events (such as; click a button to select a file and click another to send selected file), there is no problem. It is working but when i fire events immediately there is no success.

Thanks right now..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've solved my problem with [that](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4856946/218010) solution.