# Why form auto submit not working?

Tags: javascript, html

Why this accepted answer doesn't work for me?

[Automatically submitting a form when an upload file is chosen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4856916/automatically-submitting-a-form-when-an-upload-file-is-chosen)

my code:

```
<form>
<input id="id_image" name="image" onchange="this.form.submit();" type="file">
<input id="send" type="submit" value="submit" name="submit">
</form>
```

Comment: and what if user selects wrong file?

Comment: then the "wrong" file gets uploaded.. maybe a cancel mechanism?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Because you named your second input `"submit"`, which shadows the `submit` method of the form. Rename it.

For example :

```
<form>
<input id="id_image" name="image" onchange="this.form.submit();" type="file">
<input id="send" type="submit" value="submit" name="somename">
</form>
```

Answer (score -1):

The solution is simple :D

```
<form>
<input id="id_image" name="image" onchange="this.form.submit();" type="file">
<input id="send" type="submit" value="submit" name="submit2">
</form>
```

The code it's ok, but you call the input button with submit..:D

Change the name and it's ok!

Hope this Help! Bye.

Comment: Seriously, why repeat the same answer?